# Browser home page on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a custom home page that I use with all browsers on my PC at home. The files are all on my "C" drive (example):
file://homepc/Users/MyUserID/Documents/webhome/specialhomepage.html

Because it is associated with my Chrome account, when I use Chrome on my PC at work, it wants to access the same files, and can't.

Is there a way to locate the "webhome" folder so that Chrome can find it no matter what PC I'm on?

I looked at opening a web page from my Box synched files, but it still starts the URL with the very local information (example):
file:///C:/Users/WorkUserID/Box%20Sync/...

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Chrome homepage that's locally synchronized across multiple computers**

Create a folder `webhome` within your box folder. It will contain your synchronized homepage:

```
mkdir "%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%\Box Sync\webhome"
```

Create or place your `specialhomepage.html` within it:

```
notepad "%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%\Box Sync\webhome\specialhomepage.html"
```

Here's the magic. Create a junction point on all computers that point to this new folder:

```
mklink /J c:\webhome "%HOMEDRIVE%\%HOMEPATH%\Box Sync\webhome"
```

Then set your Chome home page on all computers to:

```
file:///C:/webhome/specialhomepage.html
```

All done. Chrome will use `c:\webhome\specialhomepage.html` on all your computers.  Box will synchronize the homepage across all your computers because it really exists in a subfolder of your Box folder.

Comment: The junction point is extra.

Comment: By extra, do you mean unneccessary? I suggest junction points because Chrome doesn't expand environmental variables, and unless the OP has the same username on all her computers, chrome won't point to the correct box folder on all the computers.